Nested radicals with alternating signs
Evaluate the following nested radicals
$$\sqrt{7+\sqrt[3]{7-\sqrt[3]{7+\cdots}}}$$
$$\sqrt{7-\sqrt[3]{7+\sqrt[3]{7-\cdots}}}$$
I know that I can construct a system of equations from this, like
$x = \sqrt{7+\sqrt[3]{7-\sqrt[3]{7+\cdots}}}$
and
$y = \sqrt{7-\sqrt[3]{7+\sqrt[3]{7-\cdots}}}$
Then, we will have
$$(x^2-7)^3 = y^2$$
$$(7-y^2)^3 = x^2$$
But I do not know how to go from here. I also recall this problem being shared a few years back but I couldn't find the source of it.

You can substitute one into the other and get an equation in one variable.  It is of eighteenth degree, however.  Alpha solves it numerically, so I don't think you will find an algebraic solution.  The asymmetry of having a square root out front instead of another cube root likely makes it harder.

Is it possible that there is a typo in the question, and both expressions should instead have a cube root out front, instead of a square root?  If not, I question the educational value of the problem.

That's what I thought too, but the guy who shared this confirmed to me that there is no typo. I find this a quite strange. Even though the first root is a cube one, finding the solution is still difficult.
